# Repeat an integer n times

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to make a pyramid out of an integer.
I.E the number 3 :

```
3
33
333
```

So based on the answers i found i made this :

```
int n = 8;
String n2 = Integer.toString(n);

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat(n2, i));
}
```

But it's not working and would be suboptimal. Is there a simple way to repeat an integer n times in the same line ?

EDIT : made myself a method.. not quite happy either but it seems i can't just use something like System.out.println(int x, int n times)

```
int n = 8;

for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: *it's not working* - what do you mean? And why it's *suboptimal*?

Comment: You can not build dynamic recursive structure like this pyramid without loop

Comment: I mean isn't it suboptimal to convert my int into a string ? AIn't there a direct way to deal with the integer ?

Comment: The int is converted to a String for display purposes anyway. You should avoid using words like "suboptimal" when you don't know what you're a beginner. Chances are you don't really understand what's optimal and what isn't.

Comment: Yep; i was hoping to find something like System.out.println(x, y) where x is t he integer to display and y the number of time you want to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean isn't it suboptimal to convert my int into a string ? AIn't
>   there a direct way to deal with the integer ? –

If you dont want to convert int to string.

This may help you.

```
    int n = 3;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    System.out.println(new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", n+""));
    }
```

Comment: Yes thanks thats the best answer. I found that method previously but i was thinking there could be another way but it seems not. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Happy to see this helps you :)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, you *can* do this without **explicit** loops using `Java-8` streams:

```
IntStream.range(1,n).forEach(i -> System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat(n2, i));
```

or even without `apache-commons`:

```
 IntStream.range(0,n).forEach(i -> System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i+1, n2))));
```

But in any case internally all these methods use loops.

Comment: you have also used` foreach`, i hope this is same as `for loop`

Comment: @ankur-singhal I said: "without explicit". It is obvious that `String.repeat` uses loop internally also

Comment: @saka1029 according to question `n2` is always string representation of `n`: `n2 = Integer.toString(n)`

Comment: @saka1029 but you are right in that I should increase interval to `[0,n]`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something as below.

```
public class Test{

    public static String repeat(String str, int times) {
        return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(repeat("3", i));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
3
33
333
3333
```

Comment: @Andremoniy there has to be one loop atleast

Comment: Yes my question wasn't clear. I'm fine with one loop. But i want to repeat my integer i times. However i dont know how to do that without converting my int into a string before

Comment: @ankur-singhal not actually

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

You would still have to loop, but it might be slightly better performance-wise.

```
int n = 8;
String n2 = Integer.toString(n);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    builder.append(n2);
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

This does what you want, but not in the way you think about it. Instead of repeatedly having to create the repeating integer string, we simply build ONE string, saving us the work of repeating it.

To actually answer your question, you could use this code, although I would recomend the first approach:

```
char[] str = new char[n];
Arrays.fill(str, (char)(number + '0'));
new String(str);
```

This would only work if your integer is 0 <= number < 10.

Answer (score 0):

To keep with integers, you may store last value each time, and add the next part :

i = 0 --> you get 3

i = 1 --> you get 33 (i0 + 30)

i = 2 --> you get 333 (i1 + 300)

```
int lastValue = 0;

for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {

  int currentValue  = lastValue + (n * Math.pow(10, i));
  System.out.println(currentValue);
  lastValue = currentValue ;
}
```

This obviously works for one-digit integers only.